# Feature Selection: Select top best features based on feature scores produced by different algorithms

Tags: correlation, python, scikit-learn, ranking

I like to do feature selection and I am using multiple feature selection algorithms provided by sklearn. What I have done is, use a bunch of feature selection algos and get the score for each feature. This returns a dataframe where the index is the features and columns consists of the scores returned by the different feature selection algorithms. How do I combine these different set of scores and create a single ranking for all the features? After that, what is the best way to select the top K features based on the final aggregated ranking? I am not looking for taking the mean or converting them to ranks and agg based on them. Is there a much better statistical approach? I have read about rank correlation methods like Kendall Tau,  Spearman,  Concordance correlation coefficient , Borda Count (i implemented this), etc, but I am not exactly sure how to implement them?